# How to post and get value from react native into flask

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, flask

I'm creating a simple project for this react native to integrate with flask, but the problem is a lack of knowledge and source, it's quite difficult to grasp the idea of this implementation. So the error I got is:

ERROR  ReferenceError: Property 'saveData' doesn't exist

May I know what is the best solution for this

App.Js

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function Homescreen() {
  const urlBase = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'; // Corrected variable name

  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [Sl, setSl] = useState(0);
  const [Sw, setSw] = useState(0);
  const [Pl, setPl] = useState(0);
  const [Pw, setPw] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const saveData = async () => {
      const url = `${urlBase}/predict`;

      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify({ Sl, Sw, Pl, Pw }), // Pass an object with properties
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          const result = await response.json();
          console.log('Data is added successfully:', result);
          setData(result);
        } else {
          console.error('Error fetching data from the server:', response.statusText);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      }
    };

    saveData(); // Call the function
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once on component mount

  return (
    <SafeAreaView className="flex-1 p-5 bg-white ">
      <View className=" flex-col">
        <View>
          <Text className="font-bold text-sky-700 text-center text-2xl">
            Beta Sypnapse Ai Project
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View className="m-3">
          <View className="rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-1 h-30 m-3">
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Sepal length"
              value={Sl}
              onChangeText={text => setSl(text)}
            />
          </View>
          <View className="rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-1 h-30 m-3">
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Sepal width"
              value={Sw}
              onChangeText={text => setSw(text)}
            />
          </View>
          <View className="rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-1 h-30 m-3">
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Petal length"
              value={Pl}
              onChangeText={text => setPl(text)}
            />
          </View>
          <View className="rounded-2xl bg-gray-200 p-1 h-30 m-3">
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Petal width"
              value={Pw}
              onChangeText={text => setPw(text)}
            />
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={saveData}>
            <View className="rounded-2xl bg-blue-400 w-48 h-12 self-center items-center p-3 m-3">
              <Text className=" text-slate-50 text-sm">Identify the data</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View>
          <Text className="self-center">
            The result will be : {data.prediction}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

app.py

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle
from urllib.parse import quote as url_quote
from flask_cors import CORS

# Create flask app
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))


@flask_app.route("/predict", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def predict():
    sl = request.json()
    sw = request.json()
    pl = request.json()
    pw = request.json()
    features = [np.array([sl, sw, pl, pw])]
    prediction = model.predict(features)
    return {"prediction": prediction}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_app.run(debug=True)
```

To be able to post and get value from react and python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare saveData() function inside useEffect, which means the function is accessible only in the scope of that function. I can see that you pass this function as argument on row 76:

```
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={saveData}>
        <View className="rounded-2xl bg-blue-400 w-48 h-12 self-center items-center p-3 m-3">
          <Text className=" text-slate-50 text-sm">Identify the data</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
```

For that you have ReferenceError. If you still want to pass that function to this component, declare the function inside the component, not inside useEffect.